# How can I get the express-validator to work in this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern, express-validator

I have a routes/auth.js file and a controller/auth.js file having the code as below :

```
//routes/auth.js
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const {check,validationResult} = require('express-validator');
const {signout,signup}=require('../controllers/auth');

router.get("/signout",signout);

router.post("/signup",[
    check("name").isLength({min: 3}).withMessage("Name should be of atleast 3 chars"),
    check("email").isEmail(),
    check("password").isLength({min: 3})
],signup);

module.exports=router;
```

```
//controllers/auth.js
const User=require("../models/user");
const {check,validationResult} = require('express-validator');

exports.signup=(req,res)=>{
    const errors=validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty)
    {
        return res.status(422).json({
            error: errors.array()[0].msg
        })
    }
    const user=new User(req.body);
    user.save((err,user)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).json({
                err: "There is an error"
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return res.json({
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                id: user._id
            });
        }
    })    
};
```

The express-validator is not working. When I hit the post request via PostMan the object with name smaller than 3 chars gets stored in the database. No error message is seen. Please help with this.

Comment: try `if(!errors.isEmpty())`?

Comment: Thanks man, this totally worked. I dont know how I skipped on such a basic thing. Thanks again. Cheers.